# What would be preferred site for $\rm N$ and $\rm B$ co-doping in the ethylcyclohexane?

Tags: physical-chemistry, molecules, chemical-compounds

I want to replace two carbon of ethylcyclohexane: one $\rm C$ with $\rm B$ and the adjacent $\rm C$ with $\rm N$ in my hydrocarbon. Could you please explain me with possible reason that where can I replace two carbons with B and N, i.e. in the ethyl group or in the ring. My aim is to calculate dehydrogenation enthalpy.

Comment: That is something for the [chemistry.se].

Comment: True, I tried to tag the word chemistry but I do not find it.